# What's the difference between playbackLikelyToKeepUp and AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay?

Tags: ios, video-streaming, avplayer

I'm trying to understand how to properly detect when a player item can play again.

See below observer logic:

```
if (object == playerItem && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"playbackBufferEmpty"])
{
    if (playerItem.playbackBufferEmpty) 
    {
        // show loading indicator
    }
}

if (object == playerItem && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"playbackLikelyToKeepUp"])
{
    if (playerItem.playbackLikelyToKeepUp)
    {
        // hide loading indicator

        if (playerItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay) {
            // start playing
        }
        else if (playerItem.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            // handle failed
        }
        else if (playerItem.status == AVPlayerStatusUnknown) {
            // handle unknown
        }
    }
}
```

Is checking for `AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay` underneath `playbackLikelyToKeepUp` overkill?

Or

Should I only listen to `status` change on the player item instead of bothering with `playbackLikelyToKeepUp`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The two properties inform us of two different pieces of information in regards to the status of an AVPlayerItem. `AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay` is a constant that will indicate `readyToPlay` ONLY once an AVPlayer has been given sufficient time to buffer enough of the item's data such that it is able to BEGIN playback of the item. But that is it. Just because an item is ready to play, doesn't mean that it won't stall after the first few seconds.

[`playBackLikelyToKeepUp`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1390348-playbacklikelytokeepup) returns a `bool` indicating that playback of the item is "likely" to keep up throughout the duration of the item. This property does NOT only pertain to the beginning of the item, like `AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay`. It does not "care" if the item is ready for playback, all it "cares" about is wether or not it "thinks" that playback of the item will keep up without stalling. This is a PREDICTION of playability that takes into account various factors which you can read about here -> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritemstatus

So in regards to your question, is it overkill to check the value of `AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay` after you've already checked `playbackLikelyToKeepUp`... well it is up to you. I personally would check both. I would want to ensure first that the item is ready to play, meaning that sufficient data has been buffered by the `AVPlayer` in order to begin playback. AND I would then want to ensure that `playbackLikeyToKeepUp == true` so that I can have some degree of certainty that the user's media experience won't be interrupted. But if all you care about is knowing when an item is ready to begin playback again, then you only need check the `status`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Regarding your last statements, it sounded like you had it backwards. First check AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay and then check playbackLikelyToKeepUp, which is different from my example. Which way is more correct?

Comment: If you are going to delay playback until both `AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay == true` AND until `playBackLikelyToKeepUp == readyToPlay` then i guess it doesn't really matter. Personally I would first check if `AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay == readyToPlay` and then I would go on to make sure that `playBackLikelyToKeepUp == true`. Perhaps you may only want to check `AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay == readyToPlay` , then start playing, and periodically check up on `playBackLikelyToKeepUp == true`. And if it returns `false` then you can make changing accordingly such as reducing I/O

Comment: So in answer to your comment, I feel that the proper way would be to first check `AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay` and then check `playBackLikelyToKeepUp`. Sorry for the long-winded answers

Comment: "_various factors which you can read about here_": I don't see such thing on the avplayeritemstatus page, even with Internet Archive.org, so I've added a link to playBackLikelyToKeepUp

Comment: I don't think you need to periodically check the `playBackLikelyToKeepUp`, thats when you use KVO to listen to its change. Also, note that `playBackLikelyToKeepUp == YES` doesn't guarantee `currentPlayerItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatusReadyToPlay`. You should KVO both of them as well as other flags such as `playbackBufferEmpty`, etc.